# Bounding relative error in norm of vector component of quaternion product.

Tags: numerical-methods, quaternions

I'm trying to bound the relative error that can accrue on *just* the vector component of the result of quaternion multiplication.  If you can recall, a quaternion can encode a rotation by angle $\theta$ around some axis $u$:

$$\mathbf{q} = e^{\frac{\theta}{2}{(u_x\mathbf{i} + u_y\mathbf{j} + u_z\mathbf{k})}} = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} + (u_x\mathbf{i} + u_y\mathbf{j} + u_z\mathbf{k}) \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$$

And two quaternions multiplied together, $p=qr$ represent a composite rotation which is some angle around some other axis.  The product still has the form above, so the magnitude of the vector component $||p_{xyz}|| = sin(\frac{\theta_{final}}{2})$

I'm trying to bound the *relative* error on that vector norm under quaternion multiplication, to show that you can recover the final rotation angle accurately.

In *Algorithms for Manipulating Quaternions in Floating-Point Arithmetic* (Joldeş, 2020), it's shown that you can bound the overall normwise relative error of quaternion multiplication, and that it's a relatively sedate ~5.75u.

I tried to replicate that derivation, but applied only to the vector norm.  Some quick definitions first.

The product $p = qr$ has four components, defined as:

$$
p_0 = q_0r_0 - q_1r_1 - q_2r_2 - q_3r_3\\
p_1 = q_0r_1 + q_1r_0 + q_2r_3 - q_3r_2\\
p_2 = q_0r_2 - q_1r_3 + q_2r_0 + q_3r_1\\
p_3 = q_0r_3 + q_1r_2 - q_2r_1 + q_3r_0
$$

We also define some terms $M_n$ for condition number purposes:
$$
M_0 = |q_0r_0| + |q_1r_1| + |q_2r_2| + |q_3r_3|\\
M_1 = |q_0r_1| + |q_1r_0| + |q_2r_3| + |q_3r_2|\\
M_2 = |q_0r_2| + |q_1r_3| + |q_2r_0| + |q_3r_1|\\
M_3 = |q_0r_3| + |q_1r_2| + |q_2r_1| + |q_3r_0|
$$

We can proceed as in the Joldeş paper, but just with the vector component of the quaternion ($p_{123}$)

$$\frac{\Vert p_{123} - \hat{p_{123}}\Vert^2}{\Vert p_{123}\Vert^2} \le \frac{\sum_{n=1}^3 (|p_n|v + M_nw)^2}{p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^3}$$

Where $u$ is the rounding unit, $v$ is $\frac{u}{u+1}$ and $w = 2v + 3v^3 + v^3$ (just explaining it doesn't really matter what these are).

Expanding out the quadratic up top:
$$\le \frac{\sum_{n=1}^3 (|p_n|^2v^2 + 2M_nw|p_n|v + M_n^2w^2)}{p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^3}$$

If we note that $|p_n| \le M_n$ by the triangle inequality, we can replace $|p_n|$ terms with $M_n$ in the numerator without affecting the bound:

$$\le v^2 + \frac{\sum_{n=1}^3 (M_n^2(2vw+w^2))}{p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^3}$$

or:

$$\le v^2 + \frac{(2vw+w^2)(M_1^2 + M_2^2 + M_3^3)}{p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^3}$$

At this point in the proof, Joldeş notes that all of the $\frac{M_n^2}{\sum{p_n}^2}$ terms have the same form:

$$
\frac{|\langle a,b\rangle|^2}{|a|^2|b|^2}
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are just different rearrangements of the absolute values of the elements of $p$ and $q$

Thus, by Cauchy-Schwarz, all of those terms are $\le 1$ and fall out of the bound.  That doesn't apply here since there's no $p_0^2$ term in the denominator, and I'm left sad that I don't have a nice relative error bound.

I think this is a deathblow because there's no way to get around the $q_0$ $r_0$ terms affecting the vector component and you can't bound the termwise error in general, but I wanted to see if someone else had an alternative justification to drop those terms in the bound, or perhaps an alternative approach altogether.